# Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have installed Zf2 framework on my system. 
Its working Localhost skeleton zend application sample page. 
When I insert new module in my project I am getting error:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

   Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "userscontrollerindex(alias: Users\Controller\Index)" via invokable class "Users\Controller\IndexController"; class does not exist

#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(637): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromInvokable('userscontroller...', 'Users\\Controlle...')
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(593): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Users\\Controlle...', 'userscontroller...')
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php(525): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Users\\Controlle...', false)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager.php(137): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Users\\Controlle...', Array, false)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(96): Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager->get('Users\\Controlle...')
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\CommunicationApp\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#11 {main}
```

Here attach my code:

module.config.php

```
<?php
return array(
 'controllers' => array(
 'invokables' => array(
            'Users\Controller\Index' =>
             'Users\Controller\IndexController',
             ),
            ),
 'router' => array(
      'routes' => array(
            'users' => array(
               'type' => 'Literal',
                   'options' => array(
        // Change this to something specific to your module
                              'route' => '/users',
                     'defaults' => array(
 // Change this value to reflect the namespace in which
 // the controllers for your module are found
               '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Users\Controller',
              'controller' => 'Index',
              'action' => 'index',
           ),
          ),
  'may_terminate' => true,
  'child_routes' => array(
 // This route is a sane default when developing a module;
 // as you solidify the routes for your module, however,
 // you may want to remove it and replace it with more
 // specific routes.
 'default' => array(
          'type' => 'Segment',
     'options' => array(
              'route' =>
                 '/[:controller[/:action]]',
          'constraints' => array(
                       'controller' =>
                '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                   'action' =>
                 '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
               ),
               'defaults' => array(
         ),
               ),
          ),
           ),
         ),
       ),
  ),
 'view_manager' => array(
 'template_path_stack' => array(
 'users' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
 ),
 ),
);
```

Module.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

 namespace Users;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
            ),
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
            // if we're in a namespace deeper than one level we need to fix the \ in the path
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/' , __NAMESPACE__),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        // You may not need to do this if you're doing it elsewhere in your
        // application
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    }
}
```

application.config.php

```
 <?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
         'Users',
    ),

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        //'config_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        //'config_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        //'module_map_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        //'module_map_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        //'cache_dir' => $stringPath,

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ),

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    //'service_listener_options' => array(
    //     array(
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ),
    // )

   // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
   // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
   // 'service_manager' => array(),
);
```

When I run the on My browser I receiving error

```
An error occurred
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.
Additional information:
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
```

Comment: please check have you changed class name in UserController.php Possibility you miss to change classname "class UserController extends AbstractActionController"

Comment: thank u @kamlesh.bar i will check thank u for u r comment

Comment: u mention controller.php file? no file is create usercontroller.php

Comment: File name should be UserController.php and inside that file check this  "class UserController extends AbstractActionController"

Comment: i have created indexcontroller.php  code  :                             namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70775/discussion-between-kamlesh-bar-and-sripriya).

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be in your autoload_classmap.php file.
Try editing the file to

```
<?php
 return array('Users\Controller\IndexController' => __DIR__ . '/Controller/IndexController.php',);
```

If it worked, you likely have your IndexController.php file located outside of the default directory. Advice you move content of *'Users\Controller'* folder to the *'Users\src\Controller'* and then edit the autoload_classmap.php file back to

Answer (score 0):

From your comments above it looks like you have the wrong namespace in your Users IndexController. Can you post that file? The namespace should be Users\Controller not Application\Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove `**NAMESPACE** => **DIR** . '/src/' . str_replace('\', '/' , **NAMESPACE**),

` on Module.php

and replace with `__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/'. __NAMESPACE__,),`